# Map Two Foreign key in a single table to an one PK in another table using Entity Framework Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys, entity-framework-migrations

In my ASP.NET Core MVC web app, I need to add two foreign keys from a table to a single primary key in another table as shown in this screenshot:

[Database relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4nZB.png)

When I create the model using the code shown, the migration is created successfully. But when I run `update-database`, I get multiple errors.

```
public class Shipment
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }        
    public int OriginId{ get; set; }      
    public int DestinationId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(OriginId))]
    public Location OriginLocation { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey(nameof(DestinationId))]
    public Location DestinationLocation { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Shipment> OriginShipments { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Shipment> DestinationShipments { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Shipment>(entity =>
        {
           entity.HasOne(d => d.OriginLocation)
                .WithMany(p => p.OriginShipments)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.OriginId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.DestinationLocation)
                .WithMany(p => p.DestinationShipments)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.DestinationId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
        });
}
```

Comment: What **are** those *multiple errors* ?

Comment: Mark the InverseProperty for each Navigation Property.